# What does the sentence mean exactly?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Though not on his coins, the Kharosthi script is used in Rajuvula's
>   Mathura Lion Capital Inscription, **which bears an unmistakable stamp
>   of official association.** (Singh, Abhay Kumar. 2008. *Reassessing the
>   Contribution of the Seistani Shakas in India*, Nāme-ye Pažuhešgāh,
>   Journal of the Research Institute: I.C.H.T.O, No. 22 & 23,
>   Spring-Summer: Special International Issue, The Iranian Research
>   Institute for Cultural Heritage and Tourism. p47)

Could someone please explain me the bold sentence in simple words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kharosthi script (script means "writing, using a particular alphabet") is not used on [Rajuvula's coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajuvula#Coinage_of_Rajuvula). But it IS used in his [Mathura Lion Capital Inscription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathura_lion_capital), which is certainly official. ('Official' here means Rajuvula authorized it, or commissioned it, I think.)

(Then, in brackets, the source of this information: the author, the title of the article or essay and the journal that published it.)

Later you asked,

```
The bold sentence i meant. What does "unmistakable stamp" mean here?
```

Please use a dictionary. You asked about the **sentence** and I have explained its meaning. Please find out what a sentence is. If you use a dictionary you will understand my explanation.

Unmistakable:
The word is in the dictionary. It means 'not likely to
be mistaken for anything else'.

Stamp:
Rubber stamps are used to mark official documents. The ink-mark they make on paper is also called a "stamp". These marks (stamps) are always distinctive: each one is recognizable. A document stamped with the stamp of a government department becomes official: it now bears a stamp.

Now...

Imagine a smart young man marching along the road. You might say, "He looks like a soldier." Or you might say, "He has (or He bears) the stamp of a soldier". Do you understand? It is a metaphor. He HASN'T got an ink-mark proving that he is a soldier, but we might SAY he has. He looks as if he might.

So...

The Mathura Lion Capital inscription hasn't got an ink-mark proving it is official, but we might SAY it has. We might say, it "bears an unmistakable stamp of official association."

Comment: The bold sentence i meant. What does "unmistakable stamp" mean here?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.